# How do I extract values from a kafka row via spark under structured streaming?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

Given a dataframe that I extracted from Kafka. How can I extract values from it via pattern matching?

Dataframe:

```
df = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("kafka") \
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "host1:port1,host2:port2") \
  .option("subscribe", "topic1") \
  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest") \
  .load()
```

My issue is the schema looks like this:

```
df.printSchema()

root
 |-- key: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- value: binary (nullable = true)
 |-- topic: string (nullable = true)
 |-- partition: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- offset: long (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- timestampType: integer (nullable = true)
```

That binary type is something that I can't pattern match for. How would I extract that value then parse it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question : How would I extract that value then parse it?

I assume that you are using avro message and can try as per below code snippet ( I dont know what you are trying to pattern match here) `decodeAndParseObject` function uses [twitters bijection api](https://github.com/twitter/bijection)
with below dependency

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.twitter/bijection-avro -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.twitter</groupId>
    <artifactId>bijection-avro_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

---

```
val ds = df.select("value").as[Array[Byte]].map(x=>decodeAndParseObject(x))
```

where

```
import org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord
import com.twitter.bijection.Injection
import com.twitter.bijection.avro.GenericAvroCodecs
/**
* decode and parse binary based on your schema... your logic goes here
*/
def decodeAndParseObject(message: Array[Byte]) =  {

val schema = new Schema.Parser().parse("yourschemahere")

val recordInjection: Injection[GenericRecord, Array[Byte]] = 

GenericAvroCodecs.toBinary(schema)

val record: GenericRecord = recordInjection.invert(message).get
println(record.getSchema)
record.getSchema.getFields.toArray().foreach(println)
println("\n\n\n\n\n\n Record " + record.toString.replaceAll(",", "\n"))
//get the column and do pattern matching....
// Prepare another generic record .... I'm leaving it as blank here...

record
```

}

Update:
you can use the above generic record and get the column you want using
`record.get("yourcolumn")` and do scala pattern matching case for this.

Comment: Thanks to add to this. Would you know how to do the same thing with scala pattern matching to extract the value column from the row?

Comment: in above code `record: GenericRecord`  from this `record.get("yourcolumn" )` and do scala pattern matching  case for this